# Angular change page depends on AuthService

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have AuthService with isAuth property and layout with navbar and i want to change buttons on it if user is authorised

part of navbar

```html
<div *ngIf="!this.auth.isAuth; then authorizedBlock else unauthorizedBlock"></div>
    <ng-template #unauthorizedBlock>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-2 ms-lg-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='login'>Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='registration'>Registration</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #authorizedBlock>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-2 ms-lg-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='profile'>Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
```

part of layout where im trying to get auth

```js
constructor(private auth:AuthService, private  router:Router) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    ?????
  }
```

what i need to change to make it work?

this.auth.isAuth throws error that property is private

if i make local value equals to `this.auth.isAuth` it wont change when im login

Comment: I would suggest you to make some changes to your auth service in order to become the `isAuth` property an `Observable` since this is a state of your app and you should keep track the changes of this. In this way you could subscribe to get notified when this state changes and make the required changes on your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by having a `get` function.

in `.ts` file

```
public get isAuth(): boolean {
   return this.auth.isAuth;
}
```

in `.html` file: bit of refactoring

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isAuth; else unauthorizedBlock">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-2 ms-lg-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='login'>Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='registration'>Registration</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
  
    <ng-template #authorizedBlock>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-2 ms-lg-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='profile'>Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
```

also, one more thing we don't need to use `this` keyword in `.html` file.